# how to access MySQL on OpenShift without rhc port forward?

Tags: python, mysql, openshift

We have a Web Server in our company and create a MySQL Server on OpenShift.

We need to use Python to access the database server without rhc port forward,

Can we have others way to access MySQL on OpenShift directly?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the gear directly just as you would any other Database not housed on OpenShift.

When you created the MySQL cartridge you should have been given a connection string:

```
mysql://OPENSHIFT_DB_GEAR_DNS:OPENSHIFT_DB_PORT/...
```

You can use that provided connection string and authentication to access the application.

**Note:** These strings above are environment variables on the gear, and will typicaly translate to something like:

```
mysql://app-namespace.rhcloud.com:55582/
```

This can be used from outside of the gear by other applications to access the database that is hosted on OpenShift.

**Note:** The OpenShift [forums](https://www.openshift.com/search/node?keys=mysql) have lots covering this topic.

Comment: Typically you can do the following to see all of your environment variables for an application.

ssh $(rhc apps | grep SSH | grep <app> | awk '{print $2}') env

Comment: This is only the case if you are using a paid-version of open shift. If you are using the default 'small'-gear then the mysql db can not be accessed remotely.

Comment: @SFERICH it is unfortunately not correct what you said. theAlse is right, you have to pay to do a remote conn. without port-forward.