# OpenShift MySQL from external app

Tags: php, openshift

I want to connect to OpenShift MySQL database from non-OpenShift web server. How can I do this?

I have WordPress preinstalled. (PHP and MySQL in one)
The mysql is on IP 127.3.135.2 But I can't get public IP

Comment: Surely you can through [`rhc port-forward`](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift/), but I do not know if that's what you are looking for. For a standard mysql remote connection, I suspect that it is still [reserved for not-free accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18401670/3294262). See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32055237/3294262)

Comment: Yes, I know about the rhc port forward, but is it the only way? I can't really do that on a web host. Is there any way to map port from my domain to the mysql server?

Comment: I really don't know, but I think the answer is No. You can create your own api on https.

Comment: I thought of that, but I am a bit worried about security. I have a feeling I would mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

The only ports from your gear(s) that are open to the outside world are:

- http (80)
- https (443)
- ws (8000)
- wss (8443)

And these all get forwarded to port 8080 internally on your gear.  The only way to reach the MySQL server from the outside is to use the `rhc port-forward` command.  An alternative solution is to write an API that will allow you to authenticate and query the data in your database that the other application needs.

Another, slightly more advanced solution is to host both applications on OpenShift Online, and create one of the applications as a "scaled" application, that way the database will be on it's own gear, and will be accessible by both OpenShift hosted applications.